# Filtering function on Firebase data with Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I want to apply a filter on titles of my stored data but the structure of my filtered data is not the same after filtering. The "key" of my data is deleted by the filter and replaced to an index.

Link to repository : https://github.com/Mobize/BlocNote/blob/fdb5a4e60a0094cb0d5cc80e80a3e3ffcf9347ae/src/app/single-section/single-section.component.ts#L88

Here is my database structure:
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPIwQ.png)

My items before filtering:
[Before filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqP3F.png)

After filtering:
[After filtering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TCt6.png)

My component code:

```
filter(query: string) {
    this.filteredItems = (query) ?
    Object.values(this.items).filter(p=>p.title.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "")
    .toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase())) :
    this.items; 
}
```

My template:

```
<input #query (keyup)="filter(query.value)" type="text" class="form-control search" placeholder="Recherche...">
<mat-list-item id="item_list" *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | keyvalue ; let i = index" [class.changeColor]="item.key == selectedValue">
  <a (click)="openItem(item, item.key)" *ngIf="item.value.title" matLine><mat-icon [class.yellow]="item.key == selectedValue">code</mat-icon>{{item.value.title}}</a>
  <button mat-icon-button>
    <mat-icon id="edit_item_icon" (click)="onEditItem(item)">edit</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon (click)="openDialog(item.key, item.value.title)">delete_sweep</mat-icon>
 </button>
</mat-list-item>
```

therefore when i click on an item to edit it after filtering, it creates a new item....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop through it and filter with `indexOf()`:

```js
filter(query: string) {
    const result: object = {};

    for (let key in this.items) {
      const data = this.items[key];

      if (this.items.hasOwnProperty(key) && data.title &&
        data.title.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").indexOf(query) !== -1) {
        result[key] = data;
      }
    }

    this.filteredItems = Object.keys(result).length ? result : this.items;
}
```

---

I strongly recommend you to wrap the `this.filteredItems` assignation in `ngZone.run()` if you are using in the dom:

```js
this.ngZone.run(() => {
      this.filteredItems = Object.keys(result).length ? result : this.items;
});
```

Remember to import the service in your constructor with `constructor(private ngZone: NgZone)`